# Can I add seconds to current date without using Calendar Library in Java?

Tags: java, spring, testing, calendar

*I want to get the current time in Java, and now I want to add 15 seconds above the time. Can I do this with a library **other than the Calendar library** in java?*

```
import java.util.Calendar;
    public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          System.out.println("current date = " + calendar.getTime());
          calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15); // Add 15 seconds to current date
          System.out.println("Updated Date = " + calendar.getTime());
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can, and I certainly recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). There are other alternatives too (Joda-Time, home-grown library), but I am not in doubt that java.time is superior to those. The only other option you may consider is [Time4J](http://www.time4j.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed! The [`java.time` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) was added because the `Calendar` and `Date` classes were insufficient. Something with [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) perhaps. Like,

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("current date = " + now);
System.out.println("Updated Date = " + now.plusSeconds(15));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add directly to java.util.Date,

```
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println("now : " + now);
    long seconds = now.getTime();
    seconds = seconds + (15 * 1000); //add 15 seconds * 1000 because in millis
    Date then = new Date(seconds);
    System.out.println("then : " + then);
```